# Titanium http request leak

Tags: memory-leaks, httprequest, titanium, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I have to make a load of subsequent http requests to load product images into the app as it has to function in an offline mode.
Around 2000 calls.
The http client seems toi have a memory leak which causes the persistent mbytes in "instruments" to rise to around 200 without being garbaged.

After use of the http client it is being set to null.

I have tried setting the file property of the httpclient without any success

I have set the unload function to only call the callback function which in turn calls the http send function again (thus looping through the 2000 products to get the respective pictures)

I changed from SDK 7.5.0.v20180824022007 to SDK 8.1.0.v20190423134840 and even SDK 9.0.0.v20181031080737 but the problem remains

the code of my http common module:

```
function HttpClient(options = {}) {

  this.root = options.root || "ROOT_OF_API";
  this.endpoint = options.endpoint || false;
  this.needsChecksum = options.needsChecksum || false;
  this.data = {};
  this.method = options.method || "Post";
  this.timeout = options.timeout || 5000;

  this.calculateChecksum = function () {

    var moment = require('alloy/moment');

    if (!Alloy.Models.user.authenticated()) {
      return false;
    }

    var sp = (moment().unix() - Alloy.Models.meta.get("timeDiff"))
    var hash = Ti.Utils.md5HexDigest("nX" + sp + "FossilSFAapp" + Alloy.Models.user.get('token').substring(10, 14) + "CS")
    var checksum = sp + "-" + hash.substring(4, 8)

    this.data.checksum = checksum

  }

};

HttpClient.prototype.setData = function (data) {

  this.data = data

};

HttpClient.prototype.send = function (callback) {

  // set new checksum for request if is needed
  if (this.needsChecksum) {

    this.calculateChecksum()

  }

  // add app version
  if (this.method === "POST") {
    this.data.appversion = Ti.App.version;
  }

  // send
  var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({

    onload: function () {

      callback({
        success: true
      })

    },
    onerror: function(e) {
      callback({
        message: e.messgae,
        success: false
      })
    },
    timeout: this.timeout
  });

  client.open(this.method, this.root + this.endpoint);
  if (this.setFile) {
    client.file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, this.fileName);
  }
  client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  client.send(JSON.stringify(this.data));
  client = null;

};

module.exports = HttpClient;
```

and then the module is used in the product model like so:

```
var HttpClient = require('./HttpClient');
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

function getImage (i) {

    if (collection.at(i) && collection.at(i).get('iimage0') && collection.at(i).needsImageUpdate()) {

        httpClient.endpoint = collection.at(i).get('acarticlenumber') +".jpg";
        httpClient.fileName = 'productImages/' + collection.at(i).get('acarticlenumber') + '.jpg'
        httpClient.send(function(e){

            if (i < collection.length) {
                i++
                getImage(i)
            } else {
                finished()
            }

        });

    } else {
        if (i < collection.length) {
            i++
            getImage(i)
        } else {
            finished()
        }
    }
}

// start getting images at index 0
getImage(0)
```

anyone have an idea why these memory leaks appear ?
It only ever occurs when actually sending the http request.

Comment: What do you mean by `I have tried setting the file property of the httpclient without any success`? It didn't help or it didn't work? Setting the file property will save to data to the file directly without keeping it in memory until it is loaded. Is your app crashing after the downloads? Sometimes it takes a while till the memory is released. I've downloaded very big zip files (>500MB) without any problems before or crashes. Try just using a for-loop with httclient to download the files, without the commonjs, calculateChecksum(), moment.js, Alloy.Models.meta. All these could be a cause.

Comment: saving the httprequest directly to a file with the file property didn't help. It did work but the app crashed at some point during the loops
I also tried omitting the CommonJS module and only using the normal client without any moment.js meta or calculateChecksum() but still the memory skyrockets and the app crashes eventually

I read something about the http client having leaks in sdk 7.5 with a resolution in 8.0 and 8.1. But changing to those sdk's also didn't help
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-26811